# Is there a restore counterpart to gvfs-trash?

Tags: command-line, trash, gvfs

I've used `gvfs-trash` to move an item to trash from a command-line.  Is there a way to *restore* such a file from the command-line?  I've checked other `gvfs` binaries and don't see one that makes sense?

*I know there are other projects out there* that are devoted to implementing the Freedesktop.org Trash spec.  I'm interested a `gvfs` approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the [`gvfs-bin`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=gvfs-bin&searchon=names) package, there is currently **no** restore counterpart to `gvfs-trash`, so the **only** way around it at the moment is to install [`trash-cli`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=trash-cli&searchon=names) from the repositories (more information [here](https://github.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli#readme)) and use the `trash-restore` (`restore-trash` in 18.10 and earlier releases) function from there after sending a file to trash with `gvfs-trash`. They are both compatible as they adhere to the [freedesktop trash specification](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec), as you probably know.

To send a file to trash, enter:

```
gvfs-trash newt
```

Then run

```
trash-restore
```

which gives the prompt

```
0 2012-09-13 01:09:05 /home/mike/newt
What file to restore [0..0]: 0
```

This seems to be the way to restore things sent to trash from the command-line at the moment, but it will be worth updating the answer in the future if a `gvfs` restore tool appears to compliment `gvfs-trash`.